# React Hooks: Independent state in dynamic children

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am generating my state in the parent component. `latestFeed` generates a series of posts from my backend:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { getLatestFeed } from "../services/axios";

import Childfrom "./Child";

const Parent= () => {
    const [latestFeed, setLatestFeed] = useState("loading");
    const [showComment, setShowComment] = useState(false);

    useEffect(async () => {
        const newLatestFeed = await getLatestFeed(page);
        setLatestFeed(newLatestFeed);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="dashboardWrapper">
            <Child posts={latestFeed} showComment={showComment} handleComment={handleComment} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Parent;
```

then `latestFeed` gets generated into a series of components that all need to hold their own state.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


const RenderText = (post, showComment, handleComment) => {
    return (
        <div key={post._id} className="postWrapper">
            <p>{post.title}</p>
            <p>{post.body}</p>
            <Comments id={post._id} showComment={showComment} handleComment={() => handleComment(post)} />
        </div>
    );
};

const Child= ({ posts, showComment, handleComment }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {posts.map((post) => {
                return RenderText(post, showComment, handleComment);
            })}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Child;
```

In its current form, the state of `RenderText`'s is all set at the same time. I need each child of `Child` to hold its own state.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked that `getLatestFeed` returns an array of distinct posts? (in other words: is the displayed content different from what comes out of `getLatestFeed`?) Code looks okay with regard to data display. However there are some other issues here. You should change the `RenderText` to be a React component instead of a plain function and pass the `key` prop to `RenderText` (not to the `div` within `RenderText`). Those things could be causing issues.

Comment: The content from ```getLatestFeed``` is great. It's the state ``` const [showComment, setShowComment] = useState(false)``` being generated in ```Parent``` that's non unique when pushed to the ```Child``` & ```RenderText```. When employing the ```setShowComment``` function, all ```showComment``` state stays the same across the board. I need each Child's   ```showComment``` to be unique.

Comment: Why should ```RenderText``` be a class?

Comment: Not a class, but used as a component, e.g. `<RenderText key={post.id} post={post} ... />`. You are also missing the decaration for `handleComment` in the parent?

Comment: Ignore ```handleComment```. Got rid of it for easier to read code. Why should it be a Component?

Comment: Briefly, because of lifecycle and state. If you intend to return JSX, use it as a component.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `RenderText` as a function, call it as a component:

```
{posts.map((post) => (
  <RenderText key={post.id} post={post} showComment={showComment} />
))}
```

This is because when used as a component, it will have it's own lifecycle and state. If used as a function call, React does not instantiate it the same way - no lifecycle, no state, no hooks, etc.

Comment: What if the component is first created by a function? Say a parent function does the mapping, then the Child handles all returning of JSX?

Comment: I think that would leave you in the same place as before, although I may not be visualizing it the exact same way you are describing... either way, there's a [good read here](https://dev.to/igor_bykov/react-calling-functional-components-as-functions-1d3l) that explains more of this in detail.

Comment: yeah. didn't change anything.